warning: unknown enum constant XmlAccessType.FIELD reason: class file for javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType not found
I have recently converted a maven project to gradle and then migrating from springboot 2.7 to 3x
I am using Jakarta instead of javax as it is Java 17. Most of my unit tests are now failing.
I am getting the following error:
warning: unknown enum constant XmlAccessType.FIELD
reason: class file for javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType not found
I have excluded any javax dependencies and have included required jakarta dependencies. I have tried everything I could think of to fix this
More Details
Originally I was using the following dependencies:
implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1"
implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:3.0.2"

which uses the following imports:
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

and caused the error I sent above
Reading other articles here I tried changing to an older dependency:
implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2"

which uses:
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

which does not give the same warning but the tests all still fail. For example:
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:795
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:795
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:648
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177
                        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at JaxbConfiguration.java:20
                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at BuiltinClassLoader.java:641

This issue is different than the previously linked one as:

I have ensured No javax.xml.bind Dependencies are being pulled
I have updated all dependencies to be jakarta
I have added jakarta JAXB dependencies (you can see above)
I have Excluded javax.xml.bind Transitive Dependencies
I have checked for Classpath Conflicts and there are none


I am getting the same error message, when I have a solution I will definitely add it here

For me it helped to explicitly add the following dependency to my project that is compiling/running on Java version 21:
implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2"

My project had a transitive dependency on an older version of this library causing the same error message as you had. I hope that solves your problem too.
For me this version was needed to work properly in good harmony with the jaxb in the runtime, for the unittests I used this glassfish runtime below. In the application itself I use quarkus runtimes
implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.5"

